# I wanted a 10% chance of an item entering a queue to be marked differently, could I roll a 10 sided die and mark the item if it's equal to 1?

Tags: probability, sampling

If I had an infinite stream of items entering a queue, and I wanted ~10% of them to be marked in a special manner, would it be "correct" to roll a 10 sided die each item that passed, and if the die rolled a "1", mark the item?

What made me pause and ask this question is that *I chose* the number 1, therefore it is not random. I could also choose 5, or 6. The die however, being balanced, has an equal probability of landing on a 1, 5, or 6 so it seems like it wouldn't matter. I guess I want to know if choosing the number 1 vs 5, 6 would influence the outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I wanted a 10% chance of an item entering a queue to be marked differently, could I roll a 10 sided die and mark the item if it's equal to 1?"

Yes.

And to answer your later questions, using 5 or 6 instead of 1 would not influence the outcome. It's still a 10% chance of being chosen and each "roll" is independent, so you could also theoretically change what needs to be rolled each time and it'd still be 10% probability. However, for programming and simplicity purposes, it is ideal to choose a specific number and keeping to it instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that or any process such that the chance of success on any given roll is 10%. You'd want to make sure that the trials/rolls are independent of one another.

As another example, you could have it so that the toy was "marked" if the first toy through the line coincided with a roll of 1, the second toy through the line coincided with a roll of 2, ... the tenth toy through coincided with a roll of 10, the eleventh toy coincided with a roll of 1, and so on. At each trial, the probability of success is 10% and the rolls are independent of one another.

What would *not* work is if you rolled all of your dice beforehand and THEN decided which numbers corresponded to marking the toys. That (pretty obviously) wouldn't randomly assign "marking" to toys.